# Issue using MailKit to fetch gmail emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail, mailkit, imapclient

I 'm working on an mvc application to fetch emails from my gmail account using MailKit, on my local computer it works perfectly. However, when uploading it on the host i get the "A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network".
I don't have ssl enabled on the host. 
all suggestions are appreciated I have crawled the web and tried all the solutions even S22.Imap.dll but still same error.

```
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                var ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses("imap.gmail.com");
                try
                {
                    client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, cancel.Token);
                }
                catch
                {
                    foreach (var ip in ips)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            client.Connect(ip.ToString(), 993, true, cancel.Token);
                        }
                        catch (SocketException e) //error means server is down, try other IP
                        {
                            //nothing, check next IP for connection
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                client.Authenticate(username, password);}}
```

Is this SSL Problem ? 
appreciate all the help I can get

Regards,

Comment: The error means that the server doesn't has a route to the gmail server, may be the server has access only to local network?

Comment: @Gusman
On my local computer it connects just fine, on my server it doesn't !!!

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked if the server has access to external network

Comment: Try to ping from the server to google

Comment: @Gusman since it's a shared host I don't have access to the server, I have to ask them to check it. thanx